# How to create alerts only on visible fields in SharePoint using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sharepoint

Based on a value from drop down I have hidden or shown the text area in SharePoint. Now I want to create an alert on all text area fields which are visible. But the alert pops up for all the columns which are hidden too. 
Could some one tell me how to validate this field?

```
function PreSaveAction(){
    if ($(".ms-rtestate-write[id^='txt']")[0].innerHTML == "<p>​</p>") {
        alert('Please attach deviation documents');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Try `$(".ms-rtestate-write[id^='txt']:visible")`

Comment: But I have several text area's to be validated if it is blank. It simply saves the page without leaving any message